# List Multiple Columns from Different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am creating a list and want to include columns from multiple tables. Here is my code:

```
var jobAssignments = new List<JobAssignment>
            {
                new JobAssignment { JobID = jobs.Single (j => j.Status == Status.New, j => j.Priority == Priority.High).JobID,
                    TechnicianID = technicians.Single(c => c.LastName == "Dion").TechnicianID,
                    AssignmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01")}
```

I want to display Status and Priority which come from the table "Job"
I also want to display LastName which comes from technician and Assignment date which comes from JobAssignment table.

I assume that the "jobs.Single" is wrong, but what do i replace this with?

Comment: Can you join the tables and select from their result?

Comment: Using join in linq https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx.

Comment: no, my problem is getting the "Status" and "Priority" values from the Job table. i just need to know how to fix this part: "JobID = jobs.Single (j => j.Status == Status.New, j => j.Priority == Priority.High).JobID"

Comment: Try replacing the second "j=>" with "&&"

Comment: If you are only doing it once then .Single is fine. If you are doing multiple then it might be better to do a .Select after a .Where(j => j.Status == Status.New &&  j.Priority == Priority.High).

Comment: What jobs and technicians collections look like ? Can you provide this part of the code ?

Comment: Do you have a relationship set between the two?  just join the two with Include statement.

Comment: it's now working! Thank you for all your answers :)